# POI 3.17 is not working on weblogic server

Tags: java, apache-poi, weblogic

Good day,

I tried to use POI in my application to load excel sheet. 
 everything is working fine on local tomcat but when I move it to server WebLogic 12.2 that run on Java 8, I got an error as follow.
I tried all versions from POI 3.8 to 3.17(latest) but none of them is working correctly on the server.

Error checking for java lib

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.(OPCPackage.java:141)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:97)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
>   at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
>   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
>   at javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newInstance(XMLEventFactory.java:30)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.(OPCPackage.java:141)
>   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:97)
>   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

commons-codec-1.11
commons-collections4-4.1
commons-logging-1.2
junit-4.12
poi-3.17
poi-excelant-3.17
poi-ooxml-3.17
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17
poi-scratchpad-3.17
xmlbeans-2.6.0

what could be missed? 
Note: I cannot use Maven or similer technologies.

thanks

Comment: I think your data streaming from server (chunk by chunk) while your report is generating. Wait until full response received from server. Then go for generating report. Or another concern somehow any router or switch closed the connection before receiving full data.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna the file is only 27 KB. and what I did, I got the file stream then start the Workbook works  ...

Comment: I think `com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory` exception tells us that the response xml can't unmarshall due to broken.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna do you have any idea to verify if the file is marshaled?

Comment: Looks like weblogic is shipping a broken XML parser. What happens if you swap it out for a standards-compliant one?

Comment: @Gagravarr how can I do that? the strange thing is that I am using only war lib. i am not using anything from the server class path

Comment: @MohammedAl-Hanabi, which one is your service connection (i.e `.wsdl` file) config? direct weblogic port or through any proxy (e.g `haproxy`) ?

Answer (score 2):

We found one jar file causes the issue. the name is jsr173_api.jar. once this is deleted, all works fine.